# Why was my flag declined?

Tags: discussion, flags

[This](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/114657/41024) answer is clearly invalid, given that you read the language's documentation.

I used a custom mod flag to flag it as invalid, since it prints a Unicode `☆` instead of outputting an image with a 5-pointed star (like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdhM9.png) one). My flag got declined, since there was apparently no evidence to support it.

The user didn't get warned, but I'm not sure if my flag was wrong, that's why I've asked here. The other reason might have been since the question was closed as unclear (which should have been closed as too broad instead IMO).

Note: actual flag text is hidden.

Comment: I think you have to argue that the PHP answer is invalid first, because its an established answer that is not deleted.

Comment: Feel free to downvote [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/15582/34718), which sets the precedent that outputting that Unicode character is a valid solution. I messaged the OP, but if he doesn't reply, it may be up to another user to edit the question and make it invalid to output a Unicode character as the result.

Comment: @mbomb007 It's mainly the [tag:graphical-output] tag that makes me consider that answer invalid.

Comment: Obviously you'll need one of the mods to respond to know for sure, but there are a few weird things that stand out to me. 1) `... clearly invalid, given that you read the language's documentation.` What does reading the docs have to do with validity? 2) As Nathan said, there is also a PHP answer that prints unicode that hasn't been deleted. 3) The challenge is closed as unclear. These are all strange little things I see that may have contributed to the decline.

Comment: It also wouldn't hurt to say what exactly you said in the flag for more context (assuming there isn't personal info or something in the text)

Comment: @DJMcMayhem I wanna know the exact reason, since "no supporting evidence" is a bit unclear on its own. Also, if you read the documentation, you will understand what the answer does, and consider it invalid. And there's a reason the exact flag text isn't shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I declined your flag, as well as a number of flags on [the PHP answer that inspired it](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/15582/12012).

A character glyph *is* an image; U+2606 happens to be an image of a 5-pointed star. Since the task is to print a 5-pointed star and the answer prints a 5-pointed char, it is valid.

Is it cheaty? Probably. Is it in spirit of the challenge? Probably not. Does it solve the task at hand in the most boring way possible? Yes. Do we need answers in all programming languages that simply print this Unicode character or its filled counterpart U+2605? No.

You're free to dislike the answer, and there's more than enough reason to dowvote it. You can even downvote the challenge because it allows this answer as written. What you cannot do is call the answer invalid, because it isn't.

Comment: Wouldn't the best solution be to edit the challenge to make such a solution invalid? That's the sort of thing we'd do on a new challenge to prevent such a loophole.

Comment: Wait, [tag:graphical-output] challenges can be solved using Unicode chars? Got to post a bunch of Unicode chars as such answers then.

Comment: @mbomb007 Not sure. It would certainly improve this challenge, but editing someone else's challenge with the purpose of invalidating pre-existing answers should not be done in general.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer I really hope that comment is facetious...

Comment: @DJMcMayhem No I'm really worrying if I could have "golfed" like that. Of course I won't go posting such answers *right now* :)

Comment: @Dennis Well, we could add a loophole that's disallowed by default?

Comment: @mbomb007 Loopholes don't apply retroactively, but that's a good idea to prevent future answers of this kind.

Comment: @Dennis [This has been added.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12155/34718)

Comment: Oh, so the reason is that we didn't have a loophole. That's unbelievable...